# How to get all pointer variables from a C file

Tags: c, bash, shell, ctags

I have been assigned the task to prefix with `p_` all pointer variable names in a number of C files. This must be applied to function parameters, local function data and globals.

Once I get the list, I can used `sed` to do what I want.

But how can I get the list?

Comment: But you can have a variable `int abc` in some function and `char *abc` in other, in the same file...

Comment: So a snipe hunt it is. Who did you piss off?

Comment: @rodrigo: that's true. It might not be feasible for automation after all... :(

Comment: This is nigh impossible without implementing a full C parser. It's easy for things like `int* my_pointer_var`, but much harder for e.g. `int* var1, var2`? Or if using the common C++-style `int *var`? How do you differ that from dereference? And that's just for the declarations, then you have to find the actual uses of the variables, and modify them too which is going to be even harder.

Comment: @EOF: my recent c implementation has to conform to the company's coding standards :)

Comment: Some IDEs can help you with this. For example Visual Studio. You still have to find the declaration of each variable. But once found, VS can replace all instances of it with a new name. And it is able to handle variables of the same name but different types in different contexts. Not sure if that helps you any.

Comment: perhaps you could do this sort of refactoring with the clang api. have a look at [parsing-c-in-python-with-clang](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang), [libclang api](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html)

Comment: You definitely can't do this with just sed. Consider `typedef int wtf_t[1]; void foo(wtf_t x) { wtf_t y; }` Now `x` is a pointer but `y` is not.

Comment: How many files are there? I imagine you would have to review them all once they have gone through some 'magic'  conversion - might it be safer to manually edit/refactor your files? BTW I love coding standard! :-)

Comment: @Neil: not so many (around 10-15), but they are quite hefty! For sure the manual conversion is the safest, but that is going to be really boring. Thanks for all the suggestions, guys !!!

Answer (score 2):

**It's all there in the debug info.**

See this simple example (`ptr.c`).

```
int *global_pointer;
float global_scalar;
int main(int arg_scalar, char **arg_pointer) {
  void *local_pointer;
  char local_scalar;
}
```

let's compile it and examine the result woth `objdump`

```
gcc -g ptr.c && objdump --dwarf=info a.out
```

It's not too hard to figure out. There are a few occurences of `(DW_TAG_pointer_type)`. In my example there are four of them.

```
<1><8d>: Abbrev Number: 6 (DW_TAG_pointer_type)
<1><93>: Abbrev Number: 6 (DW_TAG_pointer_type)
<1><a0>: Abbrev Number: 8 (DW_TAG_pointer_type)
<1><b8>: Abbrev Number: 6 (DW_TAG_pointer_type)
```

Note the hex numbers in front of them, and look for sections containing them in the form `DW_AT_type        : <0xb8>`. The whole section with type 0xb8 is:

```
<1><a2>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <a3>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x3a): global_pointer  
    <a7>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1        
    <a8>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1        
    <a9>   DW_AT_type        : <0xb8>   
    <ad>   DW_AT_external    : 1        
    <ae>   DW_AT_location    : 9 byte block: 3 78 8 60 0 0 0 0 0        (DW_OP_addr: 600878)
```

There is the name of the variable, and the line it was declared in. A file number too, but I have only a single source file, so it's always 1. That's all you'll need for finding it, maybe with the help of `awk`, unless you did something really ugly like declaring a global variable and then a local one having the same name, all in one line. Not likely if there is some coding standard :)

Comment: This is an *extremely* interesting approach! Moving the problem to text parsing domain is much closer to my soul than using an IDE for example (still I don't judge people who use them). I am simply surprised by how much useful information is actually there in the form of DWARF overhhead in the ELF objects. However, I have one particular problem with the `local_pointer` which is tagged with `(DW_TAG_variable)` and not with `(DW_TAG_pointer_type)` as it is expected. So, I still have to figure a few more aspects and details. Thank you so much! +1